# How merge and rotate two pdf pages to one page itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm trying create java application that merge three pdf. First two pdf I combine normal without resize and rotate. The last one pdf I want to rotate and place two pdf page into one pdf page.

I used iText 5.5.13. I tried merge two pdf and It's works.

```
public void mergePdf(List<File> pdfFiles, File outputFile) {
    try {
        Document document = new Document();
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, outputStream);
        document.open();
        for (File inFile : pdfFiles) {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inFile.getAbsolutePath());
            copy.addDocument(reader);
            reader.close();
        }
        document.close();
    } catch (DocumentException | IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I don't know how merge with rotate and resize two page into one pdf page.

Answer (score 2):

Merge:

```
public void mergeTwoPagesIntoOne(String originalPdfFile, String outputPdfFile) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(originalPdfFile);
    Document doc = new Document(new RectangleReadOnly(842f, 595f), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(outputPdfFile));
    doc.open();
    int totalPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i = i + 2) {
        doc.newPage();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i); // page #1

        float documentWidth = doc.getPageSize().getWidth() / 2;
        float documentHeight = doc.getPageSize().getHeight();
        if (i > 1)
            documentHeight = documentHeight - 50f;

        float pageWidth = page.getWidth();
        float pageHeight = page.getHeight();

        float widthScale = documentWidth / pageWidth;
        float heightScale = documentHeight / pageHeight;
        float scale = Math.min(widthScale, heightScale);

        float offsetX = (documentWidth - (pageWidth * scale)) / 2;
        float offsetY = 0f;

        cb.addTemplate(page, scale, 0, 0, scale, offsetX, offsetY);

        if (i+1 <= totalPages) {
            PdfImportedPage page2 = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i+1); // page #2

            pageWidth = page.getWidth();
            pageHeight = page.getHeight();

            widthScale = documentWidth / pageWidth;
            heightScale = documentHeight / pageHeight;
            scale = Math.min(widthScale, heightScale);

            offsetX = ((documentWidth - (pageWidth * scale)) / 2) + documentWidth;
            cb.addTemplate(page2, scale, 0, 0, scale, offsetX, offsetY);
        }
    }
    doc.close();
}
```

Rotate:

```
    public void rotatePdf(String originalPdfFile, String outputPdfFile, int degrees) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(originalPdfFile);
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        PdfDictionary dictionary = reader.getPageN(i);
        dictionary.put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(degrees));
    }
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(outputPdfFile));
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, you want to turn each page into a XObject (the PdfImportedPage in @mflorczak's answer), and draw two of them into a single page.

If you know in advance that all the pages are the same size and shape, then you can get away with deciding in advance and hard-coding how you want them to appear.  If not, you need to be able to hand a potentially VAST number of combinations in a general way.

This is called "[N-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-up)" printing, and there's plenty written about it around the internet if you'd like to learn more.  Your particular example is "2-up" printing.

1. get the sizes of the pages you want to merge
2. create a new page in your output doc large enough to hold them both
3. Create `PdfImportedPage`s of the pages you want to import
4. Draw the imported pages with the alignment and rotation you desire on the output page's `PdfContentByte`.
5. Goto 1
6. Unreachable
7. Profit!

You may want to experiment with the scales and offsets (and possibly the rotation) as vs what is provided in @mflorczak's answer, and the above general theory should help to guide you.  `PdfImportedPage` should insulate you from the source pages' rotation[s], such that you'll only need to take into account their effect borders.